# hosting fonts on azure cdn - CORS support

Tags: cdn, azure-storage, cors, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I cannot get azure blob storage hosted fonts exposed via azure cdn working in IE or Firefox.

I believe this is because of @font-face cross-domain issues (CORS) and the normal solution is to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. I know that most CDNs now support this but am assuming that Azure still doesn't. Can anyone confirm this?

If this is the case, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is no longer true, azure supports CORS

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more.aspx

and a little guide to adding fonts to your azure cdn:

http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/hosting-web-fonts-in-azure-blob-storage-using-the-new-cors-support

Comment: This can all be done from portal.azure.com now and there is even a "CORS" option.

Comment: Where can I find it? Sorry for the dumb question, but not obvious for me.

Answer (score 3):

The CDN doesn't modify the headers from the origin, so it responds with whatever headers blob storage emits. Blob storage does not support CORS headers.

I'm surprised to learn that @font-face has cross-domain restrictions, but it appears that you're right (for Firefox and IE).

If you have that option, you could put the fonts on a cloud service (rather than blob storage) behind the CDN and emit the right headers there.

Comment: You will also see the same problem if/when doing Web Audio API where you have to download audio files.  Works fine with HTML5 <audio> tag as it doesn't use CORS but Web Audio API does need it or you have to force all audio files through your website.

Answer (score 1):

Your assessment is correct.

As a workaround, our company is utilizing Google storage (which supports CORS).

I would also suggest voting up this issue so the Azure team knows how many people are running into it.

http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/2850796-support-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-via-a

Answer (score 0):

I can use fonts, without setting up the CORS option anyway. I'm linking my fonts directly to the blob storage, and not a CDN, since this one does not supports the CORS from the blob.