# cssRules is null when javascript reads css file from azure blob

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-domain

I am storing my css and javascript files on blobs in the azure. I need to read the cssRules using javascript, but the cssRules field is null.

However, when the css file is a part of the project, it successfully reads the css, and the cssRules field is not null.

How do I fix this problem? I want to store the files in blobs.

Comment: you can't read the cssRules of a cross domain css file. The stylesheet must be hosted on the same domain.

Comment: Is there any way I can allow it to read the cssRules? Since I'm using the Azure, I need to deploy a new version for every change I make (each deployment takes 30 minutes).

Comment: What about using @import. Would that work?

Comment: Only the foreign server can allow it (otherwise there would be no point in [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)) by sending proper [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) . Unfortunately it seems [azure blob does not support it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12901911/995876)