# NGINX PHP 5.6 Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, nginx, font-awesome

I've tried using my domain directly, with & without the `location {}` but it still doesn't work... And I've also tried this.

```
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

And it still gives me the same error here.

```
Font from origin 'cdnurl' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'siteurl' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm not using an Amazon S3 server (which is appearantly common for these as well?) and I am using a CDN as this is serving all of my static content.

Any assistance on how I can fix this annoyance?

EDIT: Azure CDN != Superb CDN, they have no options to enable CORS and I have no idea how to do it in their CDN. And telling me to Google it isn't helping either especially considering that when I do Google it it doesn't give me any results that will help me use their CDN and enable CORS.

Comment: Which CDN are you using? You need to set CORS on the server/CDN end to load assets from a different domain.

Comment: I'm using Superb's CDN Provider, I am new to the whole CDN thing so I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Google is your friend here - search for Superb CDN CORS settings and you should find what you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hosting fonts on azure cdn - CORS support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901792/hosting-fonts-on-azure-cdn-cors-support)

Comment: @brianlmerritt, No.. It doesn't help me at all but okay.

Comment: Raise a ticket with your CDN provider or try on their forum is best bet, unless someone here already knows the answer